# QRegExp некорректно проверяет строку на правильность

Tags: c++, регулярные-выражения, qt5

Необходимо проверять строку на соответствие регулярному выражению, если соответствует - true, если нет - false. Пользуюсь вот такой конструкцией:

```
QRegExp valide_reg("\\-?\\d{1,}\\.?\\d{1,}");/*Проверяет, является строка числом с плавующей точкой*/

valide_reg.setPatternSyntax(QRegExp::Wildcard);

isCorrect = valide_reg.exactMatch("1.34");/*isCorrect равен false, хотя это не так*/
```

В чём моя ошибка (стоит отметить, что это регулярное выражение отлично работает с валидатором для ввода дробных чисел в программе)?

Comment: Замените `QRegExp::Wildcard` на `QRegExp.RegExp`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Согласно [документации](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qregexp.html#PatternSyntax-enum), `QRegExp::Wildcard` переводит QRegExp в урезанный режим, в котором распознаются только звёздочки и вопросительные знаки: `file-*.???`.

Ваше же выражение является Perl-совместимым; для него требуется `QRegExp::RegExp`. Хотя, учитывая, что этот режим установлен по умолчанию, строку `valide_reg.setPatternSyntax()` можно вообще убрать.

Comment: Благодарю, это помогло